# data with square brackets inside sqlite DB

Tags: java, android, string, sqlite

i keep getting data with square brackets inside my sqlite DataBase [9999] [8888], what i need is simple data without [ ].

```
public class AddReminders extends Activity implements OnClickListener {

    private Button btn_addrecord;
    private EditText txtpname;

    String[] versionNames= new String[]{"8888"};
    String[] versionNames1= new String[]{"9999"};

    ProductModel pm;
    DatabaseHelper db;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.add_reminder);




            db = new DatabaseHelper(getApplicationContext());
            db.getWritableDatabase();
            pm = new ProductModel();
            pm.idno = (Arrays.toString(versionNames));
            Log.i("reminderidno", "" + pm.idno );
            db.addProduct(pm);

            db = new DatabaseHelper(getApplicationContext());
            db.getWritableDatabase();
            pm = new ProductModel();
            pm.idno = (Arrays.toString(versionNames1));
            Log.i("reminderidno", "" + pm.idno );
            db.addProduct(pm);


             txtpname = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.myEditText);
             btn_addrecord = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
             btn_addrecord.setOnClickListener(this);

    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
         DatabaseHelper db;
         ProductModel pm;

        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        switch (v.getId()) {
        case R.id.button1:

            if (txtpname.getText().toString().equals("")
                    ) {
                Toast.makeText(AddReminders.this, "Please add values..",
                        Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            } else {

                db = new DatabaseHelper(getApplicationContext());
                db.getWritableDatabase();
                pm = new ProductModel();
                pm.idno = (txtpname.getText().toString());


                Log.i("reminderidno", "" + pm.idno );
                   db.addProduct(pm);
                Toast.makeText(AddReminders.this, "Record Added successfully.",
                        Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                finish(); 
            }
            break;

        default:
            break;
        }

    }
}
```

here is my Log

```
12-02 19:28:39.398: I/reminderidno(7827): [8888]
12-02 19:28:39.448: I/reminderidno(7827): [9999]
```

to be clear i need 8888 without square brackets 
Thank you in advance

Comment: why are you using string arrays as you have only one string in both arrays

Comment: @pramod-yadav i don't know a better way to do it, i'm new in this, please help if you can,

Comment: just use simple strings  String versionNames= "8888"; similarly for versionNames1

Comment: @pramod-yadav i got an error in `pm.idno = (Arrays.toString(versionNames));` tostring "The method toString(boolean[]) in the type Arrays is not applicable for the arguments"

Comment: replace pm.idno=versionNames;  similarly for versionNames1

Comment: please @pramod-yadav what can i do, to get you reputation

Comment: i can summerize it as an answer and you can accept it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you are using only one element in array replace the array with the sting as String versionNames= "8888"; and replace pm.idno = (Arrays.toString(versionNames)); to pm.idno=versionNames; similar for versionNames1